# How many different boxes are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A candy company has an unlimited supply of cherry, lime , licorice, and orange gumdrops. Each box of gumdrops contains 15 gumdrops , with at least 3 of each flavor. How many different boxes are possible?Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have observed, correctly, that we have no choice in the flavors of 12 of the 15 gumdrops, and the only variation can occur in the 3 extra gumdrops.

The extra 3 gumdrops could be all the same flavor, in 4 ways.
Or they could be of 2 flavors in 12 ways.
Or they could be of three different flavors in 4 ways.

(You should try to verify these on your own.)

So there are $4+12+4=20$ ways to choose the extra 3 gumdrops, and this is the answer.

Comment: for all same flavor $4!/{1!3!}$  for 2 flavors $4!/{2!2!}$ for 3 different flavors $4!/{3!1!}$

Comment: I don't know why you decided to calculate it that way, but it must be wrong, because $4!/2!2! = 6$, not $12$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

To make things less complicated, first subtract $12=4\times 3$ from $15$. You must find out how many different boxes containing $15-12=3$ gumdrops are possible.

Comment: Precisely zero boxes containing "$15-12=4$" gumdrops are possible!

Comment: The answer is 20 boxes, I understand that you have 4 choices for each of the 3 gumdrops but finding out how to get to 20 boxes is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

12 of the 15 gumdrops are determined, you have only arrange the 3 remaining gumdrops into one of 4 categories. You can picture that problem this way:

viewing each * as a gum drop and each | as boundary between the four boxes, you want the number of arrangements of the following symbols:

***|||

this will count the number of ways to arrange the three "stars" around the three "bars" (the so called "stars and bars" solution). This is arrangements with repetition and the solution here is $6!/3!3! = 20$